# Can a SRV record be used in place of a reverse proxy?

Tags: dns, srv

I'm trying to understand the use case of a SRV record in DNS.

This article [enter link description here](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-srv-record/) states that "The DNS "service" (SRV) record specifies a host and port for specific services". Does this mean that a SRV record can be used to direct HTTP traffic to a specific port without a reverse proxy?

For instance, if I had example.com:80 and [www.example.com:8080](http://www.example.com:8080) can I create a SRV record that points www to [IP]:8080?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that a SRV record can be used to direct HTTP traffic to a specific port without a reverse proxy?

In theory, yes, in practice, no as web browsers do not consult `SRV` records.
You can create them, but they will have no effect.

Things will change with the new DNS `HTTPS` records, as those are already started to be used by browsers.